# What is it like for ISS astronauts to re-adjust to the Earth's gravity?

Tags: iss, microgravity, medical

ISS expeditions last up to half a year, as long as a flight to or from Mars would last. [Here](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/16586/how-would-travel-to-mars-without-artificial-gravity-affect-a-crews-initial-expe/44767#44767) I answered to a question dealing with the adaptation of Martian visitors from microgravity to Martian 0.38 g. It mentions Scott Kelly who had hard time to re-adjust to 1 g, but he was a year in microgravity. How do the astronauts on "typical" ISS expeditions re-adjust to 1 g, when returning from space after about half a year, both immediately and long-term? When can they stand up with help and when without help nor any helping tools? When are they *fully* re-accustomed to the Earth's 1 g?

I'm assuming Martian astronauts would go through the same body exercise regimen as ISS astronauts do, and adapting to Martian gravity would be even easier.

Comment: Posting as a comment since it's not a complete answer, but Chapter 17 "The Hard Thump of Reality" of Clay Anderson's *The Ordinary Spaceman* gives an extremely detailed and frank account of the first few days after returning from a long duration mission.

Comment: This is too broad, there is no one size fits all here.

Comment: @GdD Just answer when they can stand up, when they can stand up on their own, when can they walk well and when they get fully accustomed to 1g, something like that.

Comment: As I say in my comment above there is no exact answer, each astronaut is different. You can't say an astronaut will be able to stand after exactly 1 hour. I'm sure some can stand up right away, others not.

Comment: @GdD Since all go through the same exercise regimen, I think they'll be able to stand up  at around the same time. But one can give an example, a certain astronaut if you want to.

Comment: Here's a little vignette: Expedition 33 lands https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY84PEAZETE and is then welcomed to Kazakstan https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkf2-UJWMr8

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe adapting to 1g from a long 0.38g is nowhere as from 0g.

Comment: @LoveForChrist I'm sure you don't mean any disrespect, but that's not really an appropriate topic for discussion. Most landings are available in YouTube by a quick search, this sequence is just the first one I could remember that shows them from ISS through exiting the capsule to the reception ceremony.

Comment: Highly related, if not a duplicate: [Why were Space Shuttle astronauts able to walk off the orbiter?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8956) My answer says the Shuttle astronauts who were able to walk off the returning Orbiter could do so because they only spent 12 days in zero g. Astronauts and cosmonauts who stayed on the ISS for significantly longer stretches of time needed considerable assistance on landing.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica That's why I wrote adapting to Martian gravity would be even easier. Anyway Martian gravity's still high compared to other spherical celestial bodies.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thank you. Good answers by you and by Andy. However this isn't really a duplicate because this is about astronauts who stay half a year in space (as long as travellers to Mars), twice as long as the astronaut you mention.